# scenario is taken correctly but does not work validation

Tags: php, validation, yii2, rule

Hi I take user data to two models If the user clicks the checkbox (company) it show him the additional data that needs to complete. I needs to work on scenario if checbox = 1 the data fields of the form must be passed. It is my action from the controller:

```
public function actionCreate() {
        $model = new UrUserForm();
        $userDate = new UserDataForm();
        $model->scenario = 'create';

        if (($userDate->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $userDate->validate() && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) || $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {

            if ($userDate->IsCompany()) {
                $userDate->scenario = 'setFirm';
            } else {
                $userDate->scenario = 'notFirm';
                $userDate->clearData();
            }
            var_dump($userDate->scenario);
            exit();
            $userDate->saveOptionalData();
            $model->RoyalUserData=$userDate->data['Id'];
            $model->saveUser();

            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Użytkownik został dodany');
            return $this->redirect(['index']);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                        'model' => $model,
                        'userDate' => $userDate
            ]);
        }
    }
```

An my model:

```
<?php
namespace backend\modules\users\models;

use common\models\UserData;
use frontend\modules\settings\models\Profile;

use yii\base\Model;
use Yii;

class UserDataForm extends Model
{
    public $Address;
    public $NIP;
    public $CompanyName;
    public $Website;
    public $Phone;
    public $IsCompany;
    public $IsPhoneConfirmed;
    public $CreatedAt;
    public $UpdateAt;
    public $Rel_State;
    public $Rel_Currency;
    public $IsDeleted;
    public $data;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['Address', 'Phone', 'Rel_State', 'Rel_Currency','IsCompany'], 'safe', 'on' => 'notFirm'],
            [['Address', 'Phone', 'Rel_State', 'Rel_Currency','IsCompany'], 'required', 'on' => 'setFirm'],
            [['NIP','IsCompany', 'Phone', 'IsPhoneConfirmed', 'CreatedAt', 'UpdateAt', 'Rel_State', 'Rel_Currency', 'IsDeleted'], 'integer'],
            [['Address', 'CompanyName', 'Website'], 'string', 'max' => 45],
            [['Phone'], 'common\components\validators\PhoneValidator'], 
            [['NIP'], 'common\components\validators\NipValidator'],
            ['IsCompany', 'safe']
        ];
    }

    public function scenarios()
    {
        $scenarios = parent::scenarios();
        $scenarios['setFirm'] = ['Address', 'Phone', 'Rel_State', 'Rel_Currency','IsCompany'];
        $scenarios['notFirm'] = ['Address', 'Phone', 'Rel_State', 'Rel_Currency','IsCompany'];
        return $scenarios;
    }

     public function saveOptionalData() {

        $model = new UserData();
        $model->Address=$this->Address;
        $model->Phone=$this->Phone;
        $model->Rel_State=$this->Rel_State;
        $model->Rel_Currency= $this->Rel_Currency;
        $model->NIP=$this->NIP;
        $model->IsCompany = $this->IsCompany;
        $model->IsPhoneConfirmed = $this->IsPhoneConfirmed;
        $model->CompanyName = $this->CompanyName;
        $model->Website = $this->Website;
        $this->data=$model;
        if ($model->validate() && $model->save()) {
            return $model;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function clearData() {
        $this->Address = NULL;
        $this->Phone = NULL;
        $this->Rel_State = NULL;
        $this->Rel_Currency = NULL;
        $this->NIP = NULL;
        $this->IsCompany = NULL;
        $this->IsPhoneConfirmed = NULL;
        $this->CompanyName = NULL;
        $this->Website = NULL;
    }

    public function IsCompany() {

        if ($this->IsCompany == 1) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    }
```

I read the documentation but it does not help me. In the create action I created

> var_dump($userDate->scenario);
>               exit();

which indicates that there is everything okay because when checkobox is off  vardump spits: string (7) "notFirm" and when he's on spits: string (7) "setFirm." I do not know where the fault but each time validation is safe, that should work that if checkbox is on data from rules(addres, phone) should be required. Anyone see my bad and can help me?

Comment: It's probably due to the fact that you're overriding the scenarios method and both setFirm and notFirm have the same values

Comment: so what can i do in this situation?

Comment: anyone can help me? I tried everything and have the same situation

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have found an answer, but in case you haven't here's one. You're setting the scenario **after** you validate the data. Scenarios must be set before you have run the validation in order to use different validation rules.

In your code you have

```
   if ($userDate->IsCompany()) {
        $userDate->scenario = 'setFirm';
   } else {
       $userDate->scenario = 'notFirm';
       $userDate->clearData();
   }
```

But in the first if in your code you have already validated

```
if (($userDate->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $userDate->validate() ...
```

In order to use a scenario I suggest the following:

```
$userDate->load(Yii::$app->request->post();//load data into model
if ($userDate->IsCompany()) {//check if company was set and is equal to 1
  $userDate->scenario = 'setFirm';
} else {
  $userDate->scenario = 'notFirm';
}
if($userDate->validate()...)//Validation code according to the scenario
```

Comment: trust me i tried this problem was in other place i msut used to: `[['Address', 'Phone', 'Rel_State', 'IsPhoneConfirmed','Rel_Currency', 'IsCompany'], 'required', 'whenClient' => "function (attribute, value) {return ($('#checker').is(':checked')==true);}"],
            [['Rel_State', 'Rel_Currency', 'IsCompany', 'IsPhoneConfirmed', 'Address', 'Phone'], 'safe', 'whenClient' => "function (attribute, value) {return ($('#checker').is(':checked')==false);}"],`  becouse browser dont know that i click this checkobx before i click send button ;) js in rules fix that